# callback after validating a form with jqueryvalidation

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I've set up a simple contact form with a couple of required fields.
Here's some code:

```
$("#commentForm").validate();
```

A few rules are added after function instance:

```
$("#name").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    messages: {
        required: "You must type your name"
    }
  });
```

My problem is that I need to launch a callback function AFTER the validator has completed checking the fields AND has written the error messages.
I've tried with invalidHandler but it triggers before the error messages.
Do you have any solution to this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery have some plugin that can fit with your need, this one may do the trick
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: Thank you, but that form is used by my agency in many sites and I'm not going to refactory the code for all of them. A simple callback on that validator would mean a couple of lines of code to be changed instead of hundreds.

Comment: I'm not familiar with validator, so i don't know if there is a way to do what you want just with the plugin. However you can try to use try...catch...finally, here some ressource for that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch